# updating data in json server

Tags: angular, json-server

i want to update only name in my json server but when i updateName() all details of object is removed except id and updated name

```
 updateName(id: string, name: string): Observable<any> {
    const shipmentUrl = `${this.url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.put<any>(shipmentUrl, {
      name: name,
    });
```

object before updateName

```
{
    "id": "S1000",
    "name": "T-shirts(Summer2018) from Shanghai to Hamburg",
    "cargo": [
      {
        "type": "Fabric",
        "description": "1000 Blue T-shirts",
        "volume": "2"
      },
      {
        "type": "Fabric",
        "description": "2000 Green T-shirts",
        "volume": "3"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "sea",
    "type": "FCL",
    "destination": "Saarbrücker Str. 38, 10405 Berlin",
    "origin": "Shanghai Port",
    "services": [
      {
        "type": "customs"
      }
    ],
    "total": "1000",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "userId": "U1000"
  },
```

object after updateName

```
{ "name": "shoes", "id": "S1000" },
```

Comment: if your json server is a rest server and you want to change one property only, then you should try PATCH request, not PUT. PUT updates the entire object, PATCH is changing only mentioned fields.

Answer (score 2):

if your json server is a rest server and you want to change one property only, then you should try PATCH request, not PUT. PUT updates the entire object, PATCH is changing only mentioned fields.